Comparing ROC curve and AUC score of different models for binary classification
I am doing a binary classification problem. The dataset has around 100K records with 40 variables.
I have tried different ML models. First, I used a logistic regression model and ended up getting a auc score of 0.83 on the validation data. Then, I tried to use L2 regularization (ridge) on logistic regression and ended up with the same auc score as before. The ROC curve for the logistic regression and the ridge model were exactly the same. Is it possible? Should I be worried that my model is not improving even after the regularization? Although, when I checked the variable importance scores, they were different for different features in both the models (Logistic and Ridge). How can the roc curve and auc score still be the same?
I then tried XGboost model and got an auc score of 0.8. When I compared the roc curve of xgboost with my ridge/logistic model (FYI: ridge and logistic had the same curves), I noticed that the ridge/logistic model beat the xgboost model for almost the entire plot.
I fear that the ridge/logistic model is overfitting even after the regularization. Or is it possible that it can genuinely beat XGboost? Even if that is possible, I am still confused about the similar results for logistic and ridge.
Please help me understand why this might be happening.
